# Key binding with shift not working on Debian + Cinnamon

Tags: linux, key-binding

I'm trying to use a key binding with alt + shift + 1, but it is not recognized.
To check I created a personalized shortcut and when I pressed these 3 keys, it showed Alt + 1...

Thank you for your help !